# Include a distance matrix as a random effect in a mixed-effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, matrix

I am trying to construct a mixed effects model and to include in it a measure of the (genetic) distance between observations, so that closer observation from different main effect levels will **outweigh** distant observations from different main effect levels.
I have constructed a similarity matrix for this purpose but the question now is how to incorporate it (or a transformation of it) in the model. From my understanding of the `lmer` function in `R`, random effects can only be a `data frame` column not a matrix.

Any ideas how to get that incorporated?

Comment: I've used the `pedigreemm` package to do this, as documented in my answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18568/3601.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways are apparently possible:
Function `MCMCglmm()` in package `MCMCglmm` accepts both a (var-covar) matrix as well as a phylogenetic tree as an argument and function `lmekin()` in package `coxme` also accepts a var-covar matrix.

Comment: I find MCMCglmm can be difficult to program.  The package "regress" in R provides a simpler way of including a covariance matrix into mixed effects models.

Comment: right but 'MCMCglmm' is very fast and also allows to directly input a tree.