# Simulate normal distributed real data (phenotypes) from genotypic data in R

Tags: normal-distribution, mixed-model, simulation

I am trying to understand how the process of simulation works. I come from the biology, so many of this concepts are new to me.

In the firs place, I am going to define what I have available and what I need to do:

- I have genomic information (molecular markers - SNPs) of a set of individuals, this information is a set of variables that take values of 0, 1 and 2. It can be seen for example as:

```
v_1 = cbind(rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)),rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)),rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)),rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)), rep(rbinom(10,2,0.4)))
```

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    0    1    1    0
 [2,]    1    1    1    0    0
 [3,]    2    0    0    0    1
 [4,]    1    0    0    1    1
 [5,]    1    1    1    0    1
 [6,]    1    2    1    1    0
 [7,]    1    0    1    2    2
 [8,]    1    1    1    2    2
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    2
[10,]    0    1    1    1    0
```

This example can be seen as the genotypic information for 10 individuals and 5 molecular markers (SNPs). In my real data I have around 1000 individuals and 1000 SNPs.

- I want to use all my genotypic information as random variable in a mixed model context to simulate new observed data (phenotype of the individuals). The simulated data must be normally distributed (mean=0 and varaince=1) and should be only dependent of a genotypic information.
- The state of the SNPs (0, 1 or 2) should be associated to an effect in the phenotype (the sum of all the SNPs would be the total phenotype).

I am trying to program this in R. Could someone give an idea of how to do deal with this problem?

I can provide more information to define better the problem.

I already asked a similar question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61538840/simulate-normal-distributed-data-from-genetic-data-in-r?noredirect=1#comment108871412_61538840

Comment: you have a contradiction here. if there is a snp effect, then the phenotype might not be normally distributed with N(0,1). You can model the background and N(0,1) and add the phenotype effect thereafter. I think that makes more sense. I can write a quick code below, but i think there is more to this subject, and you need to think about it

Comment: Again, i am not so familiar with this field of work but a quick search shows me https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/34/17/2951/4956348 . The R code looks ok and i strongly suggest you look up the references or what has been down in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assume the genotypes to be like:

```
set.seed(111)
# number of individuals
n = 1000
# number of SNPs
snps = 2000
# you can specify it otherwise
p = rep(0.4,snps)
#gives you more flexibility 
v_1 = sapply(p,rbinom,n=n,size=2)
```

It is going to be hard to end with a phenotype that is normally distributed and has effect due to your genotype. If there's a fair amount of effect and fair amount of individuals with those effects, then there will be a heavy tail. Below is a quick try but I think a lot of thinking needs to go into simulating the effect.

Making some assumptions, 1. the background noise (i.e errors) to be $\backsim N(0,1)$ and 2. in a simplistic model, 1% of the SNPs have a small effect $\backsim N(0,0.2)$.

```
BG = rnorm(nrow(v_1))
effects = rep(0,ncol(v_1))
#specify the ones with effects, 1% 
hits = sample(1:length(effects),length(effects)/100)
effects[hits] = rnorm(length(hits),0,sqrt(0.2))

phenotype = BG + v_1 %*% effects
```

We plot the distribution, and in blue is the theoretical normal distribution, you can see the heavy tails:

```
hist(phenotype,br=50,freq=FALSE,ylim=c(0,0.4))
lines(h$mids,dnorm(h$mids),col="blue")
```

[image]

There will be situations where the distribution might shift, due to the effect of snps and how these will be distribution in the genotype. You can always scale your phenotype again to get a standard normal.

Comment: Hi, thank you, It looks very good. With you asnwer I relaize that I am most interested in the normal distriburtion of the SNP effects than in the phenotypes. I runned you it with my markers and it works well. However, I have another doubt. The aim of this is use the new simulated phenotypes to check if my real model is working well in the estimation of variance components (genetic variance from markers). So I runned my model with an Average Information REML routine and the routine stop with an error "Average inform. matrix is not positive definite", Is this error a problem of the new data?

Comment: Sorry that I cannot vote yet for my reputation, I owe you it for when I get 15 of score.

Comment: No worries.. the error comes up, i think when it calculates the covariance matrix and the eigenvalues are weird.. are you running Average Information REML package from a package?

Comment: Yes, I also think it could be a problem with the covariance matrix. Do you know what is the recommended to solve this problem? I am using the program DMU to running AI-REML. So far I have not tried to do this with a R packages...

Comment: What did you pass to DMU? quick reading seems to indicate you need to pass a kinship matrix (which is the covariance matrix) to the linear mixed model. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18563/estimating-random-effects-and-applying-user-defined-correlation-covariance-struc

Comment: or something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245132/single-level-variables-in-mixed-model-lme4-error-in-r/8247412#8247412

Comment: Yes, I am going to have a look at this. Thank you again!